# The method hasStraightCard[], int) in the type PokerHandEvaluator is not applicable for the arguments (Card[])

Tags: java

```
package poker;

public class PokerHandEvaluator {

    private static final int MAX_CARDS=5;
    private static final int MAX_VAL=13;
    private static final int MAX_SUIT=4;

    private static int totVal(Card[]cards, int value) {
        int answer=0;
        for(int a=0; a<MAX_CARDS; a++) {
            if(cards[a].getValue()==value) {
                answer++;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private static int totSuit(Card[]cards, int suit) {
        int answer=0;
        for(int a=0; a<MAX_CARDS; a++) {
            if(cards[a].getSuit()==suit) {
                answer++;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    private static int totTuple(Card[]cards, int tupSize) {
        int answer=0;
        for(int a=1; a<MAX_VAL; a++) {
            if(totVal(cards,a)>=tupSize) {
                answer++;
            }
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static boolean hasPair(Card[] cards) {
        return totTuple(cards,2)>0;
    }

    public static boolean hasTwoPair(Card[] cards) {
        return totTuple(cards,2)>1 && !hasFourOfAKind(cards);
    }

    public static boolean hasThreeOfAKind(Card[] cards) {
        return totTuple(cards,3)>0;
    }

    **public static boolean hasStraight(Card [] cards, int start) {
        for(int first=start; first<start+MAX_CARDS; first+=2) {
            int end=first+8;
            if(end==MAX_VAL+1) {
                end=1;
            }
            if(totVal(cards,first+0)==1 &&
                totVal(cards,first+2)==1 &&
                totVal(cards,first+4)==1 &&
                totVal(cards,first+6)==1 &&
                totVal(cards,end)==1) {
                return true;
            }**
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static boolean hasFlush(Card[] cards) {
        for(int a=0; a<MAX_SUIT; a++) {
            if(totSuit(cards,a)==MAX_CARDS) {
                return true;
            }
        }
                return false;
    }

    public static boolean hasFullHouse(Card[] cards) {
        boolean pokerPair=false;
        boolean pokerThree=false;
        for(int a=0; a<=MAX_VAL; a++) {
            int tot=totVal(cards,a);
            if(tot==2) {
                pokerPair=true;
            }
            if(tot==3) {
                pokerThree=true;
            }
        }
            return false;
    }

    public static boolean hasFourOfAKind(Card[] cards) {
        return totTuple(cards,4)>0;
    }

    **public static boolean hasStraightFlush(Card[] cards) {
        return(hasStraight(cards)&&(hasFlush(cards));
    }**
}
```

The parts of the code where the errors are have asterisks beside them!

I have to create a poker game for my computer science class and I created the code above and the only error that it is showing is the 'hasStraightFlush' part of my code.

The error that is coming up is the title of this question. The only part in the code above that has the error is the 'hasStraight' part. I tried to input either 'start' or 'first' after 'cards', but it still does not work. Any help would be appreciated so that I can turn in this project error free. Thanks!

Comment: Look closely at what is required for the arguments of the `hasStraight()` function.  Notice, you aren't including the `int start` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a method `hasStraight` that takes two arguments, a `Card[]` and an `int`. Then you tried to invoke it with only one argument in `hasStraightFlush`.

You need to pass in both arguments -- otherwise how is Java supposed to know what to use for the `int` value? In this case, it looks like you want 0, so that you can start checking for the straight at the beginning of the hand (that is, see if the whole hand is a straight).

```
return(hasStraight(cards, 0)&&(hasFlush(cards));
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature is `hasStraight(Card[], int)` but you are calling only `hasStraight(Card[])` in your `hasStraightFlush()` method. You need to include the `int`value also.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is this part of your code:

```
return(hasStraight(cards)&&(hasFlush(cards));
```

The method `hasStraight` requires 2 arguments: `Card[]` and `int`. You're only passing it 1 of those arguments, you need to pass it the second one as well - the int.